# couldnt run veins examples

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have omnet 5.0 sumo 0.25.0 veins 4.4
When I want to run `veins` examples I have this error:

> connection to traCI  server lost

and this is my mingwenv code:

```
<status>
    <exit-code>-1</exit-code>
    <start>1517688754</start>
    <end>1517688754</end>
    <status>Could not start SUMO (C:/program -c erlangen.sumo.cfg): [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified</status>
    <stdout><![CDATA[]]></stdout>
    <stderr><![CDATA[]]></stderr>
</status>
"
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50151
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, the execution of `sumo` fails. For some reason, it looks like you specified `c:/program` as the path of the SUMO binary. Since you did not really provide any details at all, here's a list of things to check:

- that `sumo` is correctly installed.
- that you actually added the SUMO directory to your `PATH` environment variable correctly
- that you can run SUMO by itself -- I'd recommend simply checking whether `sumo -c erlangen.sumo.cfg` works. If that's not helpful, try the same with `sumo-gui` (on windows, the executables are called `sumo.exe` and `sumo-gui.exe`)
- that you're actually executing in the folder where `erlangenn.sumo.cfg` is located.
- if you're still using `sumo-launchd.py`, make sure that you're executing this with the correct arguments (refer to it's documentation with the `--help` switch for more details).

I would encourage you to follow the [veins tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) to the letter, and if you still experience issues, report any potential bugs to the authors.